# discory.py random send random string not working

Tags: python, random, discord, discord.py

I have the following code:

```
import string
import random

@client.command()
async def rng(ctx):
    await ctx.send(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5)))
```

but for some reason it always puts out the error `'Command' object has no attribute 'choice'`.

But when I just run

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5))
```

in console it works perfectly fine and outputs the random strings I want. How can I fix this?

Edit: I used in this example `random` as command name by accident (now updated it), even with changing it to something else it still won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Because library's name and the command's name is the same. You can do 3 things to fix this:

- `import random as rand`, instead of `import random`. Then in the code, you should change `random.choice` to `rand.choice`.

```
import random as rand
@client.command()
async def random(ctx):
    await ctx.send(''.join(rand.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5)))
```

- Change the command's name to something else like `rand`.

```
import random
@client.command()
async def rand(ctx):
    await ctx.send(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5)))
```

or, the best option is

- Change the command's name to `_random`, then add `random` as command aliases.

```
import random
@client.command(aliases=['random'])
async def _random(ctx):
    await ctx.send(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(5)))
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, even after changing the command to something like `rng`